# «...Велосипеды, как и сейчас, попадали в аварии». Верны ли запятые?

Tags: запятые, как, сравнительный-оборот

Сто лет назад велосипеды, как и сейчас, попадали в аварии и участвовали в гонках. Обособлять ли «как и сейчас»?

Answer (score 1):

Да, как уже сказано,  оборот ***как и сейчас*** обособляется, но есть замечание по порядку слов в предложении.

Сто лет назад ― это детерминант, отнесенный ко всему предложению, а оборот по смыслу относится именно к нему. Расположенный в середине предложения, он смотрится неестественно.

Редактирование:  **И сто лет назад, как и сейчас, велосипеды попадали в аварии и участвовали в гонках.**

Comment: Да, такой порядок слов лучше.

Comment: Ещё союз И пришлось использовать. Как вы думаете, он здесь нужен?

Comment: В зависимости от контекста. Если это описание столетнего прошлого, то И будет лишним. А если мы смотрим с позиции сегодняшнего дня, то это И помогает правильно расставить смысловые акценты.

Comment: А мне кажется, что без И предложение просто не читается, я этот союз долго придумывала.

Comment: Вот еще такое подумалось. Здесь два И с целью услиления (И сто лет назад,  как И сейчас). Лучше обойтись без этого.  Вариант №1 (Прошлое было таким же, как и настоящее): "Представьте, что вы велосипедист начала 20-го века. Сто лет назад, как и сейчас, велосипеды попадали в аварии и участвовали в гонках." Вариант №2 (и в прошлом было такое же): "Не думайте, что в наше время жизнь велосипедиста в большей опасности. И сто лет назад велосипеды попадали в аварии и участвовали в гонках."

Comment: Вариант №3 (и в прошлом, и в настоящем есть аварии и гонки): "И сто лет назад, и сейчас велосипеды попадают в аварии и участвуют в гонках."

Comment: Всё правильно, но я говорю не о смысле (для этого нужен контекст), а о структуре предложения, оно плохо читается без И. По крайней мере мне так кажется.

Comment: После еще нескольких дней обдумывания :), пришел к выводу, что одно из двух И лишнее. Либо "И в прошлом все было так же, как сейчас", либо "И сейчас все так же, как было в прошлом". Возможны вариации, но должно оставаться только одно И.

Comment: Ладно, спасибо Вам за внимание к вопросу. Может быть, союз И здесь лишний, но тогда надо что-то менять в структуре предложения.     Без какого-либо слова в начале оно мне кажется стилистически некорректным, то есть, проще говоря, "не читается".

Answer (score 0):

**Сто лет назад велосипеды, как и сейчас, попадали в аварии и участвовали в гонках.**

[ЗНАКИ ПРЕПИНАНИЯ ПРИ ОБОСОБЛЕННЫХ ЧЛЕНАХ ПРЕДЛОЖЕНИЯ  »»   Знаки препинания при сравнительных оборотах](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=291)

> § 89. Всегда выделяются сочетания как правило, как исключение, как следствие, как всегда, как сейчас, как нарочно, как например, как теперь и др., кроме тех, что включаются в состав сказуемого: Он пришел, как всегда, неожиданно (Пауст.); Как сейчас, помню тихий июльский день (Фад.); Как правило, в этих местах бывают обильные дожди (ср.: В этих местах обильные дожди бывают как правило).
>
> Всегда выделяется оборот, начинающийся сочетанием как и: У Сметаниной, как и у Гарта, было благоговейное отношение к местам, отмеченным памятью великих людей (Пауст.); Левин сел, как и обыкновенно, с книгой на кресло (Л. Т.).